# What is ViewModelStore and viewModelStoreOwner?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewmodel

I am very confused due to this new ViewModelProvider api(ViewModelProviders is deprecated)

As with the new changes there are new Constructors also (Source code).

#### #1

```
public ViewModelProvider(@NonNull ViewModelStoreOwner owner) {
        this(owner.getViewModelStore(), owner instanceof HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory
                ? ((HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory) owner).getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()
                : NewInstanceFactory.getInstance());
    }
```

#### #2

```
public ViewModelProvider(@NonNull ViewModelStoreOwner owner, @NonNull Factory factory) {
        this(owner.getViewModelStore(), factory);
    }
```

#### #3

```
 public ViewModelProvider(@NonNull ViewModelStore store, @NonNull Factory factory) {
        mFactory = factory;
        mViewModelStore = store;
    }
```

#### Gradle Depenedency:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-rc02"
```

So These Constructor's require  `ViewModelStore` and `viewModelStoreOwner`.

#### Doc:

> @param store   {@code ViewModelStore} where ViewModels will be stored.
>
> @param owner   a {@code ViewModelStoreOwner} whose {@link ViewModelStore} will be used to
>                  retain {@code ViewModels}

---

**Can anyone define them and how to use them and what they really mean to us developer's?**

---

**is ViewModelStoreOwner==activity/fragment?**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Can anyone define them and how to use them and what they really mean to us developer's?

A `ViewModelStore` can be considered as a container that stores the ViewModels in a `HashMap`. Where the `key` is string value and value is the ViewModel being saved(`ViewModelProvider` uses a concatenation of the `string_key` + ViewModel class canonical name).

A `ViewModelStoreOwner` is merely an interface. Any class that implements the `getViewModelStore()` defined by this interface becomes the owner of `ViewModelStore`. This class then maintains the `ViewModelStore` and should be responsible to appropriately restoring it when needed.

We can implement our own version of the owner and the state based on the requirement.

> is ViewModelStoreOwner==activity/fragment?

Yes. Based on the Android source code, both `Fragment` (from `androidx.fragment.app`) & `ComponentActivity` (from `androidx.activity`) implements `ViewModelStoreOwner`. These classes maintains a `viewModelStore` and value is restored appropriately.

Comment: Can the `Application` class be a ViewModelStoreOwner?

Comment: I have successfully made my ```CustomApplication``` (which inherits from ```Application```), implement the ```ViewModelStoreOwner``` interface. And later, I've been able to use my ```CustomApplication``` as the ```ViewModelStoreOwner``` of a ```ViewModel``` which later can be easily shared accross different ```Activity```es and/or ```Fragment```s.

Comment: @xarlymg89 can you please share how? More specifically how did you implement ViewModelStoreOwner

Comment: @dejavu89 ```ViewModelStoreOwner``` is just an interface. You simply have to implement their methods.  

```class MyApplication : ViewModelStoreOwner {

    private val appViewModelStore: ViewModelStore by lazy {
        ViewModelStore()
    }

    override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore {
        return appViewModelStore
    }
}```

Comment: Well, I know it's been an old post but the thing that bothered me that once you make a component say application class a viewmodelStoreOwner by implementing its method then you have taken the responsibility of  retaining viewmodelStore during configurations change and you have to clear the viewmodelStore once viewmodelStoreOwner is going to be destroyed. Without it there is no point of making a component viewmodelStoreOwner