# How to retrieve ViewModel using viewModel(...) whose ViewModelStore is Activity itself of Activity scoped?

Tags: android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

Jetnews demo application uses this code for retrieving ViewModel https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/JetnewsNavGraph.kt :

```
    composable(JetnewsDestinations.INTERESTS_ROUTE) {
        val interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel = viewModel(
            factory = InterestsViewModel.provideFactory(appContainer.interestsRepository)
        )
        InterestsRoute(
            interestsViewModel = interestsViewModel,
            isExpandedScreen = isExpandedScreen,
            openDrawer = openDrawer
        )
    }
```

`viewModel` has documentation for the `viewModelStoreOwner`:

```
viewModelStoreOwner: ViewModelStoreOwner = checkNotNull(LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current)
```

> viewModelStoreOwner - The owner of the ViewModel that controls the
> scope and lifetime of the returned ViewModel. Defaults to using
> LocalViewModelStoreOwner.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58893398/1375882 assures that both `Fragment` and `Activity` is `ViewModelStore` - implements relevenat capability.

My question is - how can I get access to the `Activity` as the `ViewModelStore` in the `NavGraph` `composable(ROUTE)` code block (which is `@Composable` apparently) and use is as `viewModelStoreOwner` argument for creating/retrieving activity-wide `ViewModel` instance? Is this possible at all? This block is part of `@Composable` and the reference to `Activity` my induce some leaks, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

My experiments and tests show that the following works as expected:

```
composable(JetnewsDestinations.INTERESTS_ROUTE) {
        val interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel = viewModel(
            viewModelStoreOwner = (LocalContext.current as AppCompatActivity),
            factory = InterestsViewModel.provideFactory(appContainer.interestsRepository)
        )
        InterestsRoute(
            interestsViewModel = interestsViewModel,
            isExpandedScreen = isExpandedScreen,
            openDrawer = openDrawer
        )
    }
```

My understanding is that `AppCompatActivity` I can use (my `MainActivity` is of this type, I have single-activity Jetpack Compose app), but I should be very, very cautious about getting the reference to it, as detailed in [How to get activity in compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675386/how-to-get-activity-in-compose)